# Erro muito louco em registro PostgreSQL X FastReport

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, postgresql, fast-reports

Tenho varias tabelas que fazem MasterDetail entre si, não vou colocar a estrutura aqui porque é muito complexo,são 26 tabelas envolvidas.

O erro é o seguinte: numa tabela tem um registro que quando aberto pelo FastReport ele simplesmente me da um "Access violation" sem pé nem cabeça que não consigo ver qual o problema, já abri a tabela comparei a registros que funcionam e nada, nada de achar o problema.

Se eu ignorar aquele único registro ele funciona.

Editei o conteúdo da tabela onde há texto colocando um simples "x" e funcionou, a impressão que tenho que é deve ter algum caractere no meio que não é aceito pela combinação PostgreSQL x FastReport.

O usuário usa muito copiar e colar no sistema e é necessário, pois muitos documentos estão em Word para serem transportados para o meu sistema, mas não consigo identificar qual caractere vem do word que causa esse problema.

O erro esta abaixo:

```
    [Window Title]
Sistema

[Content]
EAccessViolation error raised, with message : Access violation at address 0040C0B1 in module 'perfil.exe'. Read of address F3746176

[OK]
```

No notepad++ já exibi todos os caracteres pra ver se achava, mas sem chance.

Na aplicação Delphi abro o registro sem erro, mas quando mando visualizar o relatório feito em FastReport ele da o erro.

O problema está na compatibilidade PostgreSQL e FastReport, mas já estou sem parâmetro para resolver o problema.

Comment: Tenta definir o charset a ser utilizado na conexão antes de qualquer interação com o Banco
SET NAMES='UTF-8'
ou
SET NAMES='LATIN1'

Comment: Eu já faço isso, o problema é que só no FastReport que ele grita

Comment: Então talvez o problema seja no FastReport e não no PostgreSQL?

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema usando FastReport. O problema está na hora de "printar" caracteres "nocivos". Uma forma simples seria usar uma função de Normalize() que remove ou substitui os caracteres nocivos por outros.

Comment: `{Substitui caracteres especiais por equivalentes ASCII}
Function ReplaceNonAscii(const s: String) : String;
var i, pos: Integer;
const undesiredchars: String= '/ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ';
const replaces: String= '  AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOxOUUUbBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionooooo ouuuby';
Begin 
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  for i:=1 to Length(s) do
    if (s[i] in [#32, #48..#57, #65..#90, #97..#122]) then
      Result[i]:= s[i]
    else
      begin
        pos:= AnsiPos(s[i], undesiredchars);
        Result[i] := replaces[pos+1];
      end;
end;`

Comment: @Marcos Regis essa função vai substituir caracteres acentuados, cedilhas e a fins não é?  Se for não posso usar, pois é um documento e tem que ir com as formatações corretas da nossa maravilhosa língua portuguesa, o que estava pensando é se tem como eu dar um select no banco que me mostre quais caracteres não são suportados pelo latin1, estou pesquisando como montar esse select

Comment: Por acaso já tentou usar `utf8decode` e `utf8encode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema, como envolve muitas tabelas e inner joins não foi fácil, mas achei o problema, acontece que outro programador criou uma procedure no postgres que retornava character varying de tamanho não definido e o delphi reconhece como string que tem o limite de 255 caracteres e esse result pode ultrapassar essa marca, como pra visualizar utilizo um TMemo no delphi ele não grita, mas o TfrxMemo do FastReport não estava conseguindo entender isso como uma string de tamanho 255 com mais caracteres.

Agora faz sentido o accessviolation porque o texto tentava ocupar um espaço de memoria limitado a 255 caracteres

Solução em passos:

1 - Modificar a função postgresql para que retorne tipo TEXT e não Character Varying, assim o delphi reconhece como TMemoField que é o correto
2 - Reconstruir os componentes do delphi para que peguem o novo tipo
3 - Reconstruir os componentes FastReport para que peguem o novo tipo

Agora tudo ok

Grato pela ajuda dos colegas, as vezes não dão a resposta certa, mas com suas respostas nos faz ir descartando opções que talvez não teríamos pensado.